# Ethernet not working in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet

I am having a problem connecting to my ethernet port, and the same problem persists on a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04.1, 18.04, and also of the latest Linux mint. I'm using a thinkpad t460s.

It seems to attempt to connect for a second, and then I am instantly disconnected and it shows "cable unplugged" . Can somebody please help me :-(? Here are some outputs:

`ifconfig:`

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether c8:5b:76:41:10:14  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 55  bytes 9572 (9.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf1200000-f1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10696  bytes 1093130 (1.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10696  bytes 1093130 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

here is `sudo lshw -C network:`

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: c8:5b:76:41:10:14
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotia
tion
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 l
ink=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:130 memory:f1200000-f121ffff
```

Here is `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

```
N1CET63W (1.31 )
```

When I run `sudo dhclient enp0s31f6`, it hangs...

Comment: Please clarify your release. The closest is Ubuntu Core 20 as specialist *snap* based releases use the *yy* format, unlike *yy.mm* used by server & desktops releases, but your question seems to be more a standard *yy.mm* release not a *yy* release.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Also tell us exactly what version of Ubuntu you're running... 20.04 or 20.04.1? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @guiverc it's ubuntu 20.04.1. But the problem persists in the latest version of linux mint and also ubuntu 18.04.5

Comment: @heynnema thanks! the result is `N1CET63W (1.31 )`, and i'm using a ThinkPad T460s. Do you need any other info?